# Pyodbc - read output parameter of stored procedure (SQL Server)

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm trying to get the output parameter of an SQL Server stored procedure using pyodbc. The procedure is located in SQL Server and I can insert data successfully from my program. This is part of the SP:

```
INSERT INTO Table(a,b,c,d,e,f,g) 
VALUES (@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f,@g);
SET @Result = 'Inserted'
RETURN @Result
```

When I try to read the result variable in my code it shows empty.

Comment: Have you declared @Result before trying to set it?

Comment: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Calling-Stored-Procedures

Comment: Yes, Is defined as an output parameter.

Comment: Can you share the complete SP codes and Python codes that you tried?

Comment: shared, let me know if it works@J100

Answer (score 7):

This is the call from python, I used pyodbc:

```
cursor = self.db.cursor()

sql = """\
DECLARE @out nvarchar(max);
EXEC [dbo].[storedProcedure] @x = ?, @y = ?, @z = ?,@param_out = @out OUTPUT;
SELECT @out AS the_output;
"""

cursor.execute(sql, (x, y, z))
row = cursor.fetchone()
print(row[0])
```

Then create a stored procedure with an output parameter.

Comment: I get always "pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query." message. The same code from SQL Server Management Studio works.

Comment: SET NOCOUNT ON; will help you

Comment: @gszecsenyi  
make sure your stored procedure has an output parameter.

Comment: @gszecsenyi It's quite late to ask but were you able to resolve it? I am having the same error.

Comment: @MaisumAbbas Did you try putting "SET NOCOUNT ON;" at the beginning of the sql string?

Answer (score 1):

The above answer from Printthis worked and thanks a lot, yes i also added conn.commit() after:

```
row = cursor.fetchone() 
token=row[0]
conn.commit()
```

if i put commit before fetchone, i would get an error, sequence error sqlfetch...