# Pyodbc - read output parameter of stored procedure SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm trying to read the output parameter of the stored procedure but I couldn't able to read it I have tried this approach referred from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50750101/pyodbc-read-output-parameter-of-stored-procedure-sql-server) I was getting this error `not all arguments converted during string formatting`

views.py:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def FetchSuggestionAuditAgent(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Agents = request.data.get('Agents')
        sql = """\
        DECLARE @out nvarchar(max);
        EXEC [dbo].[sp_FetchSuggestionAuditAgent] @agents = ?, @response = @out OUTPUT;
        SELECT @out AS the_output;
        """
        params =(Agents, '')
        print(params)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, str(params))
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        return Response({'Agents':row[0]})
```

Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_FetchSuggestionAuditAgent] --'div'  ,''  
 
@agents nvarchar(max),@response nvarchar(1000) OUTPUT        
AS      
BEGIN      
set @agents = replace(@agents,' ', '%')      
   
   select @response = FullName from (
select FullName from tblusers where IsActive=1
union all
select FullName from tblusers where IsActive=0
and UserRole='Snowuser'
)as a
where FullName like @agents--('%'+@agents+'%')      
 
order by FullName desc     

      
END
```

Comment: Why use an output parameter at all? That query will return *multiple* results, not just a single string value. Assigning multiple results to a *string* variable or parameter won't concatenate them, it will only return one of those values

Comment: The query can be simplified drastically too - instead of a UNION on the same table, use a single `WHERE` condition, eg `WHERE (IsActive=1 or UserRole='SnowUser') AND FullName like '%' + @agents + '%'`. This kind of text search will be slow though, as it can't take advantage of any indexes

Comment: Your method of comparing in your `WHERE` is flawed. A value like `'Sam'` could match `'Sam'`, `'Samuel'` and `'Samantha'`. I would suggest a table type parameter. Also, as an FYI, the prefix `sp_` is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial / **S**ystem **P**rocedures. It should *not* be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: Thanks for ur response. Here I work on python. However, SQL which was designed and it was running fine. I have issue in my python code where I was getting  `not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: Is there any way that I could solve this error

Comment: Your `sql` text only contains one parameter placeholder (`?`) but your `params` tuple contains two elements. That might explain the "not all arguments …" message.

Comment: even after passing `params =(Agents)` I still facing the same error @GordThompson